# AWS: Trigger event if DynamoDB table row is not updated in the last 30 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have to set up a management on an AWS process.
To keep things simple I have some clients that sends me heartbeat, let's say every 5 minutes, via SOAP requests to my SOAP server deployed on an Elastic Beanstalk NodeJS app. Every time I receive a heartbeat, I store the last time I received it on a DynamoDB table by updating a field on the table.

I now need to create a process that, if I haven't received an heartbeat in the last 30 minutes, does stuff (updates another tables, calls Lambda functions, etc). I don't know now how many clients I will have, but they will be pontentially growing with time, and connected to my server 24/7.

I was hoping on something like an event that triggers a Lambda function (or posts a message on a SNS topic) after those 30 minutes that that specific row in the table is not updated, but I don't know how to get this last part to work. This event should be checking every row in the document.

How would you do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DynamoDB with TTL, DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda for this. No need for `cron`.

When you create a new row or update an existing row, set that row's TTL to 30 minutes in the future.

When that 30 minutes is reached, it will fire up a DynamoDB stream which you can use as a trigger for a Lambda function.

This Lambda function can then do the custom processing that you want to do (i.e. updates another tables, calls Lambda functions, etc).

Take note that the original DynamoDB row will be deleted when its TTL expires. If you need to keep that record, you can let the Lambda function recreate it and set a new TTL to another 30 minutes in the future.

References:

- [DynamoDB Streams and Time To Live](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-streams.html)
- [DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda Triggers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)

Comment: So the new lambda linked to the DynamoDB stream will be called every 30 minutes no matter what, even though I probably won't need to do anything (it's unlikely that the client will go down and will not send me heartbeat). The solution you provided seems to be good, but also kind of "expensive" in terms of resources. I will probably choose this way, but if there is a method that allows me to call this new lambda **only if** I need it, I would be happier :D

Comment: A stream event is created for *any* modification to *any* DynamoDB row. So, your Lambda will be called for each modification. If that modification refers to a missing heartbeat (expired TTL), then do your thing. If not, just ignore and do nothing.

Comment: Seems legit! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure that a record in DynamoDB is deleted _immediately_ after ttl is expired, and would expect that ttl is just a recommendation. Unless otherwise stated in documentation, it is quite possible that ttl deletion happens, for example, once a day.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant

Comment: Beware though, that TTL events can take "up to" 48 hours to fire off. They are not instant as per AWS.

Comment: To stress @olpa's comment, according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html): "DynamoDB typically deletes expired items within 48 hours of expiration." One cannot assume the TTL will fire exactly at the time specified. Unfortunately, this answer is not a reliable solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to check in 30 minutes interval across all clients: this can be done by a cron job on a server that executes an SQL statement where Date()- Timestamp > 30 min ( just stating the logic ), in the DynamoDB format just changes the syntax.

or you need to check after 30 minutes from the last time a particular client sent you. 
in this case your cron would be run every minute with same logic as above

if you need to use lambda in a schedule  refer to this link [Using Lambda in schedule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)

Hope this helps
if you need further help in the syntax i m ready to help